# how i can check value of "DropDownList" in asp.net with js?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm new in asp.net and java script.
i want to check value of asp:dropdownlist' with java script.

selected value define in database but when i select an item with value 9 i didn't get back "hello" alert.any body can help me ? thanks.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function offermessage() {
        var a = ($('#<%=offermessage.ClientID %> option:selected').val());
        if(a==9)
        {
            alert("hello");
        }
    });
</script>

   <div class="col-12">
       <asp:DropDownList ID="offermessage" CssClass="farsi-font drp-down-list" required="" runat="server" >
           <asp:ListItem Value="Baseid">value</asp:ListItem>
       </asp:DropDownList>
   </div>
```

Comment: where are you calling  `offermessage()` ?

Comment: <div class="col-12">
                   <asp:DropDownList ID="offermessage" CssClass="farsi-font 
     drp-down-list" required="" runat="server" >
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Baseid">value</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </div>

Comment: top comment is my html part and i don't know how i should call my function

Comment: @Masha please add the html in question .. also if you want to get the value while changing the dropdown then add it on `change` event handler

Comment: please check my answer

Comment: thanks a lot for your attention,your answer is absolutely correct.

Comment: you are welcome . please mark my answer so that it will help others

Answer (score 0):

can you try with the below code

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
            function offermessage() {
            var a = $('#<%=offermessage.ClientID%>').val();
            if(a == 9)
            {
                alert("hello");
            }
          }
        });
```

if you want to get the value of the dropdown on `change` event of dropdown then you can add below code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#<%=offermessage.ClientID%>').on('change',function(){
    var a = $(this).val();
      if(a == 9)
      {
       alert("hello");
      }
 });

});
```

Comment: @Mahsa you are welcome .. can you please mark this as answer?